# Opening a new page within a window C++

Tags: c++, forms, window

Well I'm programming a little game on visual studio with c++ and windows forms. I know that you can't have new pages within a window or atleast there is no feature for it. So my question is, is there any workaround to do so?.. or I'm totally wrong with that.

If it's not really clear what I mean then let me try to explain it a little bit. Most of you know those installation executives where you press the NEXT button and another pages pops up within the same window. That's exactly what I want.

I hope you can help me,thanks in advance.

Comment: No you got me wrong, I'm not asking you to do the work for me. What I'm asking for is if there is a way to archieve that functionality.

@LPs already helped me and gave me a point to refer to.

Comment: I use the code I posted as Answer usually for all my wizard-like application. It works fine form me. Remeber to set it as correct if you achive your goal with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a TabControl object and in the constructor of your form add

```
tabControl1.ItemSize = new System.Drawing.Size(0, 1);
tabControl1.Multiline = true;
tabControl1.SizeMode = TabSizeMode.Fixed;
```

Lines above make `TabPages` without the possibility to be selecetd by user.

Then you can create `TabPages` and switch them using `SelectedIndex` property of TabControl

Change the apparearance of tiles to Button.

The code is c#, is simple to be translated to c++.

Comment: Tried it out, this solution seems pretty good but this looks kinda odd tho. http://puu.sh/dBEAU/2ae24acd01.png. How do you deal with that?

Comment: Oh I fixed it, I changed the appearance property to Buttons. However now I'm fully satisfied with your solution. Thanks a lot!

Comment: That's right. That's the way.I forgot to write it. Prego!